# $f(x) > 0$ , prove that $\int{f} > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

Let $f$ be a function such that $ \forall{x}, f(x) > 0 $ and is integrable in $[a,b]$

prove that:
$ \int_a^b{f(x)} > 0$ or show a counter example

Comment: Hint: It should be very clear from whatever definition of integration you are using that $\int_a^b f \geq 0$.  So the only question is whether for some integrable function $f$ with $f >0$, we could have $\int_a^b f =0$.

Comment: Do you have some knowledge is measure theory ?

Comment: no knowledege in measure theory

Comment: If you are not studying measure theory, then you are considering Riemann integration? Consider any Darboux undersum. It must be greater than zero and thus the integral is greater than zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not using measure theory:** Suppose $f$ is Riemann-integrable, then it's easy to see that $\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm d x\ge0$. We are to prove $\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm d x=0$ is impossible.

If $\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm d x=0$, then $\forall \varepsilon_1>0$, we can find a separation of $[a,b]$ such that the upper Darboux sum is less than $\varepsilon_1(b-a)$. Thus, there must be a subinterval $[a_1,b_1]$ such that the maximum of $f$ on $[a_1,b_1]$ is less than $\varepsilon_1$.

Do this for $\int_{a_1}^{b_1} f(x)\mathrm d x=0$, choosing $0<\varepsilon_2<\varepsilon_1$. We get $[a_2,b_2]$, on which the maximum of $f$ is less than $\varepsilon_2$.

Let $\varepsilon_n\to0$, and there is a $c\in\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty[a_n,b_n]$. But this leads to $f(c)=0$, a contradiction.

Similarly argument shows that $f(x)=0$ a.e. on $[a,b]$. However, using measure theory will make it much simpler.

Answer (score 6):

**Using measure theory:** Suppose that $f$ is measurable. We note that
$$
\bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} \{x \in [a,b] : f(x) > 1/n\} = [a,b]
$$
It follows that there exists an $n$ such that $A_n = \{x \in [a,b] : f(x) > 1/n\}$ has non-zero measure.  We may therefore conclude that
$$
\int_{[a,b]} f \geq \int_ {A_n} f \geq \frac 1n \mu(A_n) > 0
$$